# How to compare present and end dates from a database in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to run loop on database rows to compare my present and end date whenever I start my website.

Is this is possible?

```
crowdfundingEntities4 dc = new crowdfundingEntities4();
Table p =dc.Tables.Where(model => model.status.Equals("clear"));
```

My `Index` action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is possible. However, this may need some clarification - what do you mean by "whenever I start my website"? Once websites are started they are very rarely stopped. Do you stop and start yours frequently, and if so, why?

Comment: The sample code doesn't seem to deal with dates

Comment: Basically i want to delete my data from database when enddate becomes equal to present date.So i need that when index controller run it just check all the rows either date become equals or not.